# How to give a user access to issues in GitHub but not to be able to see code in a private repository?

Tags: github

I have a private repository in GitHub. I would like to give some users access to be able to create issues. But, I don't want them to view code. How can I grant them such access in GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it has not been possible for the past decade.

Only working "solution" is to ["create a issues-only repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-an-issues-only-repository).

Although this option is not ideal to work with, as referencing code commits becomes more complicated and error-prone.